# mysql: substring that returns the first occurrence from the right? (subrstring?!)

Tags: mysql

is there a way to return the first occurrence of a space from the right side of the string in sql?

Comment: do you want the index, or a `" "`?

Comment: or the text after the rightmost space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, a brief browse through the function list didn't pop up any "search backwards" functions at me, but what you could do is reverse the string and search forwards:

```
SELECT LENGTH(`haystack`) - POSITION('needle' IN REVERSE(`haystack`))
```

Answer (score 34):

I think you are looking for something like [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('first second end', ' ', -1);
+----------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('first second end', ' ', -1) |
+----------------------------------------------+
| end                                          |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [REVERSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) in conjunction with [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_instr).

i.e.

```
select right('12345 67 8', instr(reverse('12345 67 8'), ' '));
```

returns '8'.