# How to seperate last name and first names into two new columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

How do I seperate the Last Name and First Name into new columns?

I have "John & Anna Smith" in one column, I need to separate it into "John & Anna" & "Smith" in two columns. How do I do this?

There is no delimiter when we go from left. While we go from right the delimiter is space. The last sub-string is always the Last Name. The rest is the First Names.

For Example:

"John Smith" -->  "John" in column1    and       "Smith" in column2

"John & Anna Smith"  --->   "John & Anna" in column1  and "Smith" in column2

Comment: what is the delimiter, once its the second & , once is a space ......

Comment: Do it by hand -- there's nothing that will cover every possibility.

Comment: @OMG Ponies- I have 1.5 million records :(

Comment: Nothing I can do about that.  If you want data quality, you have to put in the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, you can try something like this

```
SELECT REPLACE('John & Anna Smith', SUBSTRING_INDEX('John & Anna Smith', ' ', -1),'') AS first_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX('John & Anna Smith', ' ', -1) AS last_name;
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace 'John & Anna Smith' in this query with the all the records in a column? and also to have result set added to the current table?

Comment: It's just an idea. You can have to do it rest.

Anyway to update the table you have to do something like this, 

`UPDATE table_name SET first_name = REPLACE(name_field, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name_field, ' ', -1), last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(name_field, ' ', -1)`

Note: This QUERY is not tested.

Answer (score 1):

> For Example:
>   "John Smith" --> "John" in column1 and "Smith" in column2
>   "John & Anna Smith" ---> "John & Anna" in column1 and "Smith" in column2

You will have to come up with the **rules** or **set of rules**(to cover additional possibilities) to be able to crop the names out. One way could be to maintain the rules in some config/xml/table, so that you can add the rules there, even if you come across other types of separators/delimiters or conditions.

You can start with look for last space in a name. For instance, in case of the example above, you are splitting the text with the last *space* in a string.

Comment: How do I split a text based on the last space in the name? I'm trying to do that, but how I do that?

Comment: @Shyam Natraj Kanagasabapathy: You might find some help in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056558/mysql-substring-that-returns-the-first-occurance-from-the-right-subrstring).