# Mysql get substring before the last occurence of string

Tags: mysql

I want to get the substring of a string from beginning to last occurence of a search string.

**Example string**: *"Abcd Corp is a good org to work with. Abcd corp incorporated"*

**Search String**:  *"Corp"*

**Expected output**: *"Abcd Corp is a good org to work with. Abcd "*

ie. get the string uptil the last occurrence of search string.Could anyone suggest the best way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql: substring that returns the first occurance from the right ? (subrstring?!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056558/mysql-substring-that-returns-the-first-occurance-from-the-right-subrstring)

Comment: In your example, the expected output should be: `"Abcd Corp is a good org to work with. Abcd corp in"` since the last "corp" is inside the word "incorporated".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an way, probably not the most efficient way:

```
mysql> set @a = "Abcd Corp is a good org to work with. Abcd corp incorporated";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring(@a, 1, length(@a) - length('corp') - instr(reverse(@a), reverse('corp')) + 1);
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| substring(@a, 1, length(@a) - length('corp') - instr(reverse(@a), reverse('corp')) + 1) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Abcd Corp is a good org to work with. Abcd corp in                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Substring_index function

```
 select substring_index("Abcd Corp is a good org to work with. Abcd corp incorporated.", "corp", 1)
```

Note : This query only works when Copr available in two time. If more then two then you need to change the function parameter.

Comment: Doesn't seem too useful if you need to know how many occurrences of the search string there are beforehand...